# Struts 2 ognl.SecurityMemberAccess warning

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, ognl, valuestack

In an struts 2 project I get the ognl warning while doing a loop like this:

```jsp
<c:set var="unitArray" value="${fn:split(unit, ',')}" />

<c:forTokens items="${key}" delims="," var="name" varStatus="counter">    
    <s:text name="%{#attr.unitArray[#attr.counter.index]}" />   
</c:forTokens>
```

The warning is

```
    Package of target [javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status@353a1d92] or 
      package of member [public int javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status.getIndex()] are excluded!
```

Can this be solved?!

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve here? Why not to just iterate `unitArray`?

Comment: Dear @AleksandrM , this just some part of codes, I can put full code here, if you think it will help. But I want to know why `{#attr.unitArray[#attr.counter.index]}` generates warning and if can be solved

Comment: Q: Why? A: Because `javax` is in the `struts.excludedPackageNames`. Can you rewrite your code to get value in jstl tags and pass it to `<s:text>`.

Comment: I've run into several weird situations when trying to mix struts and JSTL tags, and most have been resolved by avoiding mixing the two. Instead of using c:set and looping with JSTL forTokens, maybe try using the Struts set and iterator tags instead. See https://struts.apache.org/docs/iterator.html and https://struts.apache.org/docs/set.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the status variable's value to the value stack and use it instead of JSTL tag's status index.

```jsp
<c:forTokens items="${key}" delims="," var="name" varStatus="counter"> 
    <s:set var="idx">${counter.index}</set>   
    <s:text name="%{#attr.unitArray[#idx]}" />   
</c:forTokens>
```

---

Or use the opposite manipulation, just put the action to the page context and use its text property in `<c:out>`. I didn't use this approach but you can try.